# What is the difference of an `if` statement that has an {open-close} brackets, and without {open-close} brackets

Tags: php, javascript, syntax

`if` statement has an *open* `{}` *close* brackets

```
  if(example){
      return example;
  }else{
      return example;
  }
```

`if` statement without *open* `{}` *close* brackets

```
  if(example)
      return example;
  else
      return example;
```

Can anyone explain to me about the *pros* and *cons* of using them? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I tried to migrate this to [so] where it belongs, but the migration failed.  Programming questions are better suited for [so] than here.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I apologize for my question, that's why I tried to ask here because I could not ask there anymore :( sorry for that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in PHP or JavaScript for example; except that, with the brackets, it is easier to add instructions later without breaking your code (you are less likely to forget to add the brackets that become mandatory).

Comment: also, personally, I find it a bit easier to visualise the start and end of the if or the else.